# How to update all of my dotnet global tool by one command

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-tool

I install too many dotnet tool but how to keey they in lastest version. I do not want to update them manual.

I find the github issus: [Add `dotnet tool update --all` option · Issue #10130 · dotnet/sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10130)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write a tool that can update all dotnet tool

### Installation

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnetCampus.UpdateAllDotNetTools
```

### Usage

```
dotnet updatealltools
```

[dotnet-campus/dotnetCampus.UpdateAllDotNetTools: The dotnet tool that can update all dotnet tools](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/dotnetCampus.UpdateAllDotNetTools)

Answer (score 2):

you can also run this (linux)

`dotnet tool list -g | awk '{ print $1 }' | tail +3 | xargs -I % sh -c 'dotnet tool update -g %;'`

from: https://lab.steveoams.com/-/snippets/15

Answer (score 2):

There is also a dotnet change request on github with some powershell samples

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10130